# Typo3 with login, salted and rsa

Tags: authentication, rsa, typo3, saltedhash

we have a Typo3 plattform that has fe_login, salted and rsa activated. When i create a FE User in BE and check the MySQL user has salted password. In fronend the user logs in with RSA, but the fe_login doesnt work...

http://dev.contextoo.net - maybe someone has any advice?

Comment: I just get a "The requested page does not exist" for the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have set the RSA feature for fronend "[FE]" and backend "[BE]" in the install tool.
To check if everything has been configured correct, checkout "TYPO3 Backend -> Reports -> Status Report".

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Sys Folder where the FE Users are stored, right?

Did you select that Sys Folder as "User Storage Page" in your login form plugin settings?

Or if you want to set this by TypoScript, you can use this line (replace 123 with your folder uid):

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.storagePid = 123
```

And: FE Users need to be in a FE User group in order to be able to log in!

http://wiki.typo3.org/Felogin